# Need help in Power BI to display data using multiple dimension tables

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling

I am pulling data from SQL Server and am now attempting to create visuals with that data. I have created the relationships between the tables in the Model View, but when I attempt to add data columns my visuals break, claiming no relationship can be found between tables. I have tables that are connected through 2 or more others. Here is an image as an example:
[image: Model View]

I am trying to display the Order Number, stored in the Order table, then all the SKU's with their price and quantity. The SKU is grabbed from the Product table, using a relationship to the OrderItem table by the ProductID. And finally, where the visual breaks, is trying to grab the CategoryID from the the Product_Category_Mapping table.

I figure since each ProductID has only 1 CategoryID I should be able to grab that and help filter down the Order's by the Category.

Comment: Make your life easier. Create a view that has Product information, including Category and Subcategory. You're thinking in terms of an OLTP database, and PowerBI works best with a Star Schema, so use the force and create a star schema in PowerBI... MUCH easier.

Answer (score 0):

> I figure since each ProductID has only 1 CategoryID I should be able to grab that and help filter down the Order's by the Category.

That's not what your model says:

[image]

It says that one Product can have many CategoryIds.